# Trying to set a canvas to maximum size while maintaining aspect ratio and centering

Tags: html, css, typescript, canvas

I am building a game in the HTML canvas, and in order to simplify things I have decided to build the game at a fixed resolution of 1920x1080. I will do that by automatically changing the transform scale property of the div containing my canvases using this function:

```
function rescale(): void{
  var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
  var scale = Math.min(width/1920,height/1080);
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = ` scale(${scale})`;
}
```

And this CSS for the container:

```
#container{
    background-image: url("Images/Background.png");
    border:2px solid blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This results in very weird behavior, where when the window is Fullscreen the canvas is too far up to the top left, and when the canvas is resized and too small it is too far off to the bottom right. Here is a link to a video of this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUlOs00bLs-QY8wbB1eP1JCeXUG-WyEk/view?usp=sharing

Could anyone tell me a how to fix this or a better way of doing this?

Comment: What have you used as the transform origin?

Comment: By changing it top left I was able to fix the problem, thank you

Comment: Suspected as much!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can solve with only css:

```
   <style>
.container{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1525041/pexels-photo-1525041.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
    border:2px solid blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    aspect-ratio: 1920/1080;
}</style>

<div class="container">s</div>
```

and if you want to fixed size, then you should use width, height, min-width or max-width